# How to parse html data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have trouble using this broken code to extract data from html . could any one tell me what is wrong with it? here is example in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/AjM7u/3/

```
var data = [];

var htmlData = '<li>';
htmlData += '    <a href="/mango/" >';
htmlData += '    <img src="./season/123434mango.jpg" width="180" height="148"';
htmlData += '         alt="mango season" class="png"></a>';
htmlData += '';
htmlData += '    ';
htmlData += '        <div class="thumbnail_label">ok</div>';
htmlData += '    ';
htmlData += '';
htmlData += '  <div class="details">';
htmlData += '    <div class="title">';
htmlData += '      <a  href=';
htmlData += '      "/mango/"> mango</a>';
htmlData += '      <span class="season">2</span>';
htmlData += '    </div>';
htmlData += '    <ul class="subject">';
htmlData += '      <li>read</li>';
htmlData += '    </ul>';
htmlData += '    <ul class="sub-info">';
htmlData += '      <li class="location">Europe</li>';
htmlData += '      <li class="price">2</li>';
htmlData += '    </ul>';
htmlData += '  </div>';
htmlData += '</li>';

console.log($.parseHTML(htmlData));

$($.parseHTML(htmlData)).each(function() {
    $(this).find("img").each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        data.push({
            SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
            HREF: parent.find("a").attr("href"),
            LOCATION: parent.find(".location").text(),
            price: parent.find(".price").text(),
            season: parent.find(".season").text(),
            thumbnail: parent.find(".thumbnail_label").text(),
            SUBJECT: parent.find(".subject li").text()
        });
    });
});

function outputData() {
    var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += "SRC: " + data[i].SRC;
        html += "<br/>HREF: " + data[i].HREF;
        html += "<br/>LOCATION: " + data[i].LOCATION;
        html += "<br/>PRICE: " + data[i].price;
        html += "<br/>season: " + data[i].season;
        html += "<br/>thumbnail: " + data[i].thumbnail;
        html += "<br/>SUBJECT: " + data[i].SUBJECT;
        html += "<br/><br/>";

    }

    return html;
}

$("#output").html(outputData());
```

output:

```
SRC: ./season/123434mango.jpg
HREF: undefined
LOCATION:
PRICE:
season:
thumbnail:
SUBJECT:
```

expected output:

```
SRC: ./season/123434mango.jpg
HREF: /mango/
LOCATION:Europe
PRICE:2
season:2
thumbnail:ok
SUBJECT: read
```

Comment: img doesn't have a href parameter the a tag does

Comment: `HREF`, for one, is never being defined in `data.push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You missed to `HREF` in `data.push`

2) `parent`(your variable) refers the  tag only, so `.find()` fails here

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
parent.parent().find(".location")  // fails eventually
```

therefore it should be `parent.parent()`

```
data.push({
            SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
            HREF: parent.attr("href"), //missed to add it
            LOCATION: parent.parent().find(".location").text(),
            price: parent.parent().find(".price").text(),
            season: parent.parent().find(".season").text(),
            thumbnail: parent.parent().find(".thumbnail_label").text(),
            SUBJECT: parent.parent().find(".subject li").text()
        });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjM7u/8/)

Comment: thanks all for reply. now href got fixed but location and price and season and thumbnail label and subject are all empty! how i can fix them ?

Comment: @Pete No I haven't stole your answer.  I was busy working in the JSFiddle, I didn't even load your answer just now I saw it.

Comment: thanks user1671639 and the rest. Now it got fixed . http://jsfiddle.net/AjM7u/10/

Answer (score 1):

What you missed is that the parent of the image is the anchor tag. What you want is:

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
```

Then the rest will fall into place. Obviously you need the missing href piece as well, as mentioned by the other posters:

```
data.push({
        SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
        HREF: parent.attr("href"),  // you missed to add this 
        LOCATION: parent.find(".location").text(),
        price: parent.find(".price").text(),
        season: parent.find(".season").text(),
        thumbnail: parent.find(".thumbnail_label").text(),
        SUBJECT: parent.find(".subject li").text()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
        HREF: $(this).parent().attr("href")
        LOCATION: parent.find(".location").text(),
        price: parent.find(".price").text(),
        season: parent.find(".season").text(),
        thumbnail: parent.find(".thumbnail_label").text(),
        SUBJECT: parent.find(".subject li").text()
```

Comment: Missing comma after HREF line

Answer (score 0):

You also were incorrect in a number of your jQuery traversal methods. The parseHTML routine should look like this:

```
$($.parseHTML(htmlData)).each(function() {
    $(this).find("img").each(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        data.push({
            SRC: $(this).attr("src"),
            HREF: parent.attr("href"),
            LOCATION: parent.parent().find("div").next().closest('ul').next().find('.location').text(),
            PRICE: parent.parent().find("div").next().closest('ul').next().find('.price').text(),
            season: parent.parent().find("div").next().find('span').text(),
            thumbnail: parent.parent().find("div").html(),
            SUBJECT: parent.parent().find("div").next().closest('ul').find('li').text()
        }); //END .push
    }); //END .find("img")
}); //END .parseHTML
```

Here is a corrected jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AjM7u/11/